# Focus on input on each step of Angular wizard

Tags: html, angular, dom, wizard

**Environment**

- Angular 8
- AZ-Wizard

**Requirement**

We need to have the first (or a specific) element get focused when the user moves to a step. Each step will have its own different elements (input, button, dropdown etc) which should get auto-focus so user doesn't have to manually click the one to start the flow.

**Code tried**

1. Use `autofocus` tag on elements. This doesn't works apart from the 1st element as with wizard, the whole set of steps is a single DOM.
2. Use ngOnViewEdit event and ViewChild on desired element in each step's component to set the focus

   ngOnViewEdit() {
       var emailElement = (this.email.nativeElement);
       if (emailElement) {
           emailElement.focus();
       } else
       alert("Email element not found");
   }
   This also doesn't works somehow. Also tried with wrapping the method's body with a `setTimeout` call with timeout varying from 0 to 1000.
3. In the wizard's `stepEnter` try to access the ViewChild and do the focus attempt. This also failed to work

*Component UI*

```
`<aw-wizard-step (stepEnter)="setFocus()">
    <app-cost-impact></app-cost-impact>
</aw-wizard-step>`
```

*Component TS*

`setFocus() {
    var emailComponent = <AddEmailComponent><unknown>this.wizard.currentStep;
    var emailElement = (<HTMLInputElement>emailComponent.email.nativeElement);
    if (emailElement) {
      emailElement.focus();
    } else
      alert("Email element not found");
  }`

**Challange**

We need to figure out some way to access the elements for each step and make it generic enough to handle all steps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try passing the id of the input element to setFocus method and change the setFocus method as below:

```
  setFocus (id: string) {
        setTimeout(() => {
          var inputEl= document.getElementById(id);
          if (inputEl) {
            document.getElementById(inputEl).focus();
          }
        }, 0);
      }
```

Component UI:

```
    `<aw-wizard-step (stepEnter)="setFocus('inputElementId')">
        <first-component></first-component>
    </aw-wizard-step>
    <aw-wizard-step (stepEnter)="setFocus('anotherElementId')">
        <second-component></second-component>
    </aw-wizard-step>
    `
```

In this way, you can just declare the setFocus method once in the corresponding typescript file and can use it for any number of components by passing in the id of the input element.

Answer (score 1):

this can solve this just pass a element to `setFocus` method then run focus method.

```js
  setFocus(elm:HTMLElement){
    setTimeout(() =>{
       elm.focus();
    })
  }
```

template

```
<aw-wizard>
 <aw-wizard-step stepTitle="Title of step 1" (stepEnter)="setFocus(email)">
        Content of Step 1
        <button type="button" awNextStep>Next Step</button>
        <button type="button" awNextStep>Go directly to third Step</button>
        <input type="text" placeholder="email" #email>
 </aw-wizard-step>
 <aw-wizard-step stepTitle="Title of step 2" awOptionalStep (stepEnter)="setFocus(age)">
        Content of Step 2
        <button type="button" awPreviousStep>Go to previous step</button>
        <button type="button" awNextStep>Go to next step</button>
        <input type="text" placeholder="age" #age>
 </aw-wizard-step>
</aw-wizard>
```

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-fgbusv)

Comment: The content of each step is a dedicated component, so would the element be available directly like that?

Comment: @malbarmavi, you need't put the "1" in setTimeout function. a setTimeout say to Angular:'Hey, wait a moment, you execute this instructions after you had finished all the others functions and you has paint the application", so the correct is simply `setTimeout(() =>{elm.focus();})`

Comment: @NitinSingh you can defined a method in each component to set the focus then call this method ,check the demo the first step is base of this

Comment: is it possible that a generic setFocus be defined once and the element to be focussed passed via the component. Single Responsibility applied. Otherwise the demo works fine

Comment: @NitinSingh I was just thinking about move the `setFocus` logic to another class as base then extends all step base component from that class  you can check the demo 